# Failure to create database with flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

please; can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?, i tried to connect to my postgre sql database with flask sqlalchemy but i keep having an error that ***db is not defined***. NB: all modules are installed and loaded successfully.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:....'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.Text)
age = db.Column(db.Integer)

def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

def __repr__(self):
    return "Name:{}\tAge:{}".format(self.name, self.age)

def create_database():
    db.create_all()

    print('Database created....')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_database()
```

Answer (score 1):

First do a pip for `sqlalchemy_utils` i.e. `pip install sqlalchemy_utils`

and then,

You need to use engine for creating the DB:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

engine = create_engine("postgres://localhost/somedb")
if not database_exists(engine.url):
    create_database(engine.url)

print(database_exists(engine.url))
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your concern, i tried your code just the way you said but i'm still having an undefined variable error.

Comment: here is the error: if not database_exists(engine.url):
NameError: name 'engine' is not defined, i really cant figure out what the issue is.

Comment: did you do a pip install for the library ?